# not able to display image from a folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring boot 1.4.3, I created a class to try to access a folder from ther server

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${img.app.path}")
    private String imgAppPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) { 
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/home/bob/bin/");
    }
}
```

In `/home/bob/bin/` I have many image:

When I try to access to http://localhost:8080//img/logo.png

I get:

```
2016-12-28 22:35:44.690 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.690 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.691 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.691 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.691 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2016-12-28 22:35:44.691 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/img/logo.png'; against '/logout'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.691 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2016-12-28 22:35:44.692 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /img/logo.png' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-12-28 22:35:44.692 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2016-12-28 22:35:44.692 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /img/logo.png' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2016-12-28 22:35:44.692 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2016-12-28 22:35:44.692 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /img/logo.png' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2016-12-28 22:35:44.692 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-12-28 22:35:44.693 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.693 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.693 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.693 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.693 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.693 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.694 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.694 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.694 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/img/logo.png'; against '/rest/**'
2016-12-28 22:35:44.695 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object - authentication not attempted
2016-12-28 22:35:44.695 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /img/logo.png reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-12-28 22:35:44.716 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@738bf2c8
2016-12-28 22:35:44.717 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-12-28 22:35:44.718 DEBUG 10000 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need allow access to the static resources with spring security.

```
<http pattern="/img/**" security="none"/>
```

[Java Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html)

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/img/**");
```

And change the resource path.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("file:///home/bob/bin/");
```

Detail see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)